# How to determine Material-UI toggle ON/OFF state from DOM?

Tags: toggle, material-ui

Inspecting toggles on http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toggle there is an input tag of type 'checkbox' in DOM. 'Toggled by default' has attribute 'checked' but when I turn it to OFF state then attributes in underling 'input' tag does not change and 'checked' is still present. 
How to determine toggle ON/OFF state from DOM?

p.s.
I am writing automated functional tests using Selenium web driver.

Answer (score 5):

If you can assign a custom `data-*` prop to each `toggle`, try this:

```
handleToggle = (event) => {
  // here's your checked Value
  event.target.getAttribute('data-isToggled') 
}

// ...React boilerplate

<Toggle
  label="Toggled by default"
  onToggle={this.handleToggle}
  data-isToggled={this.state.Toggled}
  toggled={this.state.Toggled}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't directly check toggle state from the DOM. You have to use javascript callbacks to determine if a toggle switch is on or off.

**Class ToggleComponent Example**

```
      export default class ToggleComponent extends React.Component {

      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {Toggled: true};
      }

      handleToggle() {
        this.setState({Toggled: !this.state.Toggled});
        console.log(this.state.Toggled)
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Toggle
                label="Toggled by default"
                defaultToggled={this.state.Toggled}
                onToggle={this.handleToggle.bind(this)}
                toggle={this.state.Toggled}
              />

          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Look at: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html

Comment: I am writing automated functional tests using Selenium web driver and I don't have access to React components, so I need to determine toggle state from DOM.

Comment: Why Selenium? React works on a virtual DOM, you can use [Jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html) for testing components. Anyway, check this answer: [How do you test a ReactJS Web App with Selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23350401/how-do-you-test-a-reactjs-web-app-with-selenium)

Comment: This doesn't provide a real answer for the question.

Comment: nor is this a proper callback, should have been 
this.setState({toggled: !this.state.Toggled}, ()=>console.log(this.state.Toggled))